# Is It Possible to have the Compiler Automatically Optimize my "OR" Statements?

Tags: c#, optimization

Is there a way to make the C# compiler optimize my `OR` clauses in an `if` statement?

For example:

```
if(Function_that_returns_boolean() || boolean_value)
{
    // Do something here...
}
```

Could have hugely different execution times than

```
if(boolean_value || Function_that_returns_boolean())
{
    // Do something here...
}
```

depending on how much work `Function_that_returns_boolean()` actually does internally.

---

It's unlikely (and perhaps impossible) that the compiler could know exactly how efficient `Function_that_returns_boolean()` is, and all of my *(brief)* testing indicates **OR** statements are always processed left to right, even under using the most aggressive compiler optimizations.

**Is this already handled by the compiler** *(i.e. am I mistaken)*? If not, are there any hints I can give to it?

Maybe something like an `Attribute` that lets the compiler know that it's free to rearrange my code (and if not present, to leave it be)?

```
[OrStatementUsage(Speed.Fast)] // Always push statement left when possible
public bool Fast_function_that_returns_boolean()
{
    return a + b == c; // fast
}

[OrStatementUsage(Speed.Slow)] // Always push statement right when possible
public bool Slow_function_that_returns_boolean()
{
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
    return a + b == c; // slow
}
```

(Note: all methods in the statement would have to be tagged and side-effect free to be candidates for rearrangement)

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6373h346.aspx ctrl-f for "short-circuit"

Comment: @zerkms I'm not sure I follow. I understand short circuiting, but I'm trying to short circuit by evaluating `y` first in the statement `x||y`

Comment: @Michael: it is relevant to your "and all of my (brief) testing indicates OR statements are always processed left to right" - so, it **always** is processed left to right.

Comment: No, this is *not* handled by the compiler or the jitter.  They could not possibly do so, the fact that the called method might have side-effects cannot be ignored.

Comment: @Hans I didn't even have to edit my question to mention that the methods needed to be side-effect free, as I saw this response coming ;)

Comment: @zerkms I understand that's the default behavior. Just like you can force a method to NOT be inlined, I was wondering if you could force a method to potentially be rearranged in an `OR` statement

Comment: How are you imagining that the compiler would know which side was faster without actually running both sides?

Comment: @ObliviousSage As the method designer I could easily guess under certain circumstances (imagine I have 2 functions, `bool IsMD5Match(string input)` and `bool IsSHA1Match(string input)` ... I know right away which one is faster/slower and can be moved left/right).

Comment: That's how *you* would know, which is how *you* can decide which order to put them in. How do you expect the *compiler* to know which is faster, and why would the designers of the language bother to implement a way when you (who we've already established can tell which is faster) can just put them in order based on speed?

Comment: @ObliviousSage I can't police users of an API that I write. What I *can* do (or was wondering about - hence the question) is prevent them from accidentally doing something stupid (i.e. calling a *really slow, input-only reliant, side-effect free* function at the beginning of an `if` statement with multiple `OR`s)

Comment: No, there is no way to do that. As Eric Lippert will readily tell you, features cost time/money (from a limited supply) to design/implement/test/ship. There's no reason to put in a way to tell the compiler how to optimize conditionals when the programmer can simply put the conditionals in the appropriate order. You should indicate in your documentation that the function is slow and then move on; if your users can't be trusted to use your API competently, that's their problem & not yours.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57060/discussion-between-michael-and-oblivious-sage).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the first argument is evaluated, and if it is `true`, the second argument is not evaluated at all. It is called *"short-circuit" evaluation*.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6373h346.aspx.

There is no way to instruct the compiler to evaluate the second argument of `||` first.

Comment: This doesn't answer my question. I asked (paraphrasing) "is it possible to let the compiler know it's free to rearrange `x||y` into `y||x` under the right circumstances," not "does `y` get evaluated in `if(x||y)` when `x` is true."

Comment: @Michael The answer is "No". There are no attributes to change this behavior. The link provides explanation how `||` works, it does not mention any way how to change the evaluation of Boolean operations. (I updated the answer.)

Answer (score 6):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6373h346.aspx

> The conditional-OR operator (**||**) performs a logical-OR of its **bool** operands. If the first operand evaluates to **true**, the second operand isn't evaluated. If the first operand evaluates to **false**, the second operator determines whether the OR expression as a whole evaluates to **true** or **false**.

The first operand will always be evaluated. This is a very important guarantee:

```
if (obj == null || obj.foo == "bar")
```

If the compiler could reorder the conditions here, it would change the functionality of the program.

The compiler can't know whether a given reordering would affect the result -- both because it can't in general know what the result will be and because it doesn't know what parts of the result are important. Maybe you *want* a long delay, or the first calculation does something important for the correctness of the program.

Comment: You can add attributes to tell the compiler to inline (or not to inline) your method ... I don't see my question as very different.

Comment: Inlining doesn't materially affect the semantics of the program. Changing the order of evaluation for a short-circuiting operator does. The compiler should only perform optimizations that are compatible with the code that the programmer has written.

Comment: given booleans `bool_a` and `bool_b`, are the statements `if(bool_a || bool_b)` and `if(bool_b || bool_a)` not functionally equivalent?

Comment: Only in general if they are both pre-computed boolean variables or constants, in which case there is no advantage to rearranging them.

As an example, `bool_b` could be a property that may have side effects, or throw an exception if `bool_a` is not true. In that case, rearranging the condition would cause the program to behave differently.

Comment: @Michael If they're both existing pre-calculated boolean variables then they are functionally equivalent. If either is a method that returns a boolean then they are **not** functionally equivalent.

Comment: @ObliviousSage If they can be guaranteed side-effect free and independently executable (for example, relying on only their input parameters and nothing global), does that make a difference?

Answer (score 2):

No, boolean logic operators are always short-circuit evaluated. In case of an `or`, the second part might not even be evaluated if it already evaluated to true. For instance:

```
if(ReturnTrue() || SlowOperation()) { /* ... */ }
```

Assuming that `ReturnTrue()` returns true, `SlowOperation()` is never called. The compiler cannot make optimization based on some arbitrary assumptions

Comment: I thought I was pretty clear in the question that I understood that the compiler couldn't determine that automatically. I was asking whether there was a framework in place (i.e. providing a "hint" to the compiler, like you can when determining to inline/not to inline methods)

Comment: "The compiler cannot make optimization based on some arbitrary assumptions" --- compiler could do that actually. That's what database optimizers do. And for constant `true`/`false` expression compiler *could* optimize it to even remove the whole `if` statement entirely. `var flag = false; if (flag && SomethingElse()) {...}` <--- here `if` could be just removed from the compiled unit.

Comment: @zerkms: `SomethingElse()` can still return true, so the if cannot be removed (it can be removed with `&&`). But that's not an arbitrary assumption, that's just computing a constant value. If the compiler were to shuffle operands of logical operators, it would have to take side effects into consideration, since execution order determines which operands get evaluated and which don't.

Comment: @knittl: I agree. My point was that compiler might do some nice optimizations based on short circuiting.

Comment: The statement `if(bool_a || bool_b || bool_c)` makes no difference as to which order `bool_a`, `bool_b`, and `bool_c` appear. I'm asking whether there is a built-in way to make a side-effect-less method behave this way.

Comment: @Michael: well, then the answer is as simple as "no, you can not give the compiler any hints on boolean expression evaluation order". And how would you re-arrange nested/parenthesized expressions?

Comment: @Michael: that depends. If `bool_a` (or any of other identifier) is a property with a getter, it can very well make a difference. And no, there is **no built-in way** (and I doubt you can easily extend the compiler via custom attributes)